# Grid view customization

Tags: c#, asp.net

In a `GridView` where `auto generate columns` is set to `true`, can I insert a column  manually to perform subtraction operation, from where the subtraction is to be performed based on the columns in grid.

Let's take this example :

Now, we need to bind this subtracted value to separate columns of grid view and display the result.
How to Achieve this. Any

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @RaviKiran What's your datasource ?Why not add column in your datasource directly before binding to gridview ? Give it a try.

Comment: Read this to see if it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735376/is-it-possible-to-databind-to-an-extension-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra column in your `data-source` before binding it to your `GridView` or you can also dynamically add `TemplateField` to your `GridView` , It's really hard to give satisfactory answer for your question without knowing much about details ,However try  below link .

[HERE](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-TemplateField-Column-dynamically-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can change it on `RowDataBound` event of `gridview`.

You can display your data in the footer row as follows

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {
      Label lbl = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTotal");
      lbl.Text = grdTotal.ToString("c");
   }
 }
```

Not that lblTotal is a label in the footer template.

```
 <FooterTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server" />
 </FooterTemplate>
```

Comment: thank you for reply please check my question once, i had edited now....

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, one of the drawbacks of the GridView is that it does not have a `AppendDataBoundItems` property. If you really really need the GridView, you should manipulate your datasource to give out additional "dummy rows".
Then, in the `RowDataBound` event, you would recognize those dummy rows by a certain index (I would use negative IDs, for example), and do whatever you need in that event.